# Why I can use geodatabase created by 10.5.1 in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

According to http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/manage-data/geodatabases/client-geodatabase-compatibility.htm, if the client is using 10.1, he can open geodasebase up to 10.4.

But, when I save a copy of 10.5.1 mxd to 10.1 and try to use the geodatabase created by 10.5.1, it works.

I am worrying that I missed something. Can anyone confirm it is actually supported?

Comment: It is absolutely ***not*** supported.  It may work, but nothing about 10.1 functionality is now supported. You're just observing an artifact of the format not having changed since 10.0.

Comment: @Vince So, in order to use the database, I need to create a new GDB that is 10.1 version?

Comment: 10.1 was Retired, so asking if anything done using 10.1 is **supported** is pointless. 10.3 and higher can easily make FGDB data which isn't *functional* with 10.1